# sql find within daterange

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Let's say we have two tables

```
Table A:
col_1,   col_2,   col_3,   col4
04/04/2017 1800.00  200.00 B123
21/04/2017 1800.00  200.00 B123
14/09/2017 1200.00  300.00 B123
18/12/2017 1100.00  150.00 B123
21/01/2018 1100.00  150.00 B123
06/05/2017 2400.00  500.00 A345



Table B:
col_1,   col_2,   col_3,  col4
05/04/2017 1800.00,  200.00 B123
12/09/2017 1200.00,  300.00 B123
20/12/2017 1100.00,  150.00 B123
08/05/2017 2400.00   500.00 A345
```

I want to do something like

```
select * from A 
where (col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4) 
    not in (select +/- 2 days_of_col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4 from B.
```

Can it be done. if so how.

Thanks in Advance for help...

EDIT: @Gordon.
Say table A had the additional rows as below

```
05/04/2017 1800.00  200.00 B123
05/04/2017 1800.00  200.00 B123
06/04/2017 1800.00  200.00 B123
```

this would be marked as exists. I tried using

```
count (*) OVER (PARTITION BY col_1, col_2 ORDER BY col_1, col_2)  AS count_col_2,
count (*) OVER (PARTITION BY col_1, col_2 ORDER BY col_1, col_3)  AS count_col_3
```

and putting a check on the count as in your solution. This detects only the same date multiple entries.
Hope you can suggest something.
Thanks Again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `not exists` is your best bet:

```
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b
                  where b.col_2 = a.col_2 and b.col_3 = a.col_3 and b.col_4 = a.col_4 and
                        a.col_1 >= b.col_1 - interval '2 day' and
                        a.col_1 <= b.col_1 + interval '2 day'
                 );
```

Comment: There is a situation in which this fails. I have explained It in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this might work too:

```
 select * from A a
 left join B b
 on a.col_1 between dateadd(-2, dd, b.col_1) and dateadd(2, dd, b.col_1)
 and a.col_2 between dateadd(-2, dd, b.col_2) and dateadd(2, dd, b.col_2)
 and a.col_3 between dateadd(-2, dd, b.col_3) and dateadd(2, dd, b.col_3)
 and a.col_4 between dateadd(-2, dd, b.col_4) and dateadd(2, dd, b.col_4)
 where b.col_1 is null
```